# How do I delete all my comments?

Tags: support, comments, api, rate-limiting, deleted-comments

I want to delete all of my comments, but the [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/$ID/delete` API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment) has a limit of 20 deletions per day. 
I don't want to call it every day for months, so is there a faster way?

**Update:**
Is it possible to remove the limit for my application only? (Application id: 16663)

Comment: You can't even delete 20 comments under different posts from the site, so if anything, you would need to remove that rate limit first, which is unlikely to happen. See:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: Write a cronjob that calls the API for you once every day.

Comment: Why do you need to delete all of your comments at all? Were they all this bad to deserve it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've noticed that a mod rewrote my comment to something I didn't intent to write. This won't happen again if there would be no comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to do it faster; according to [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/295232) you

> Can only delete own comments under 20 posts per day (multiple comments under same post are treated as one)

This limit applies to both the API and the regular site. Per-app exceptions to the rate limits haven't been made before; the only exceptions I know of are increased [daily quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle); [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector#smokedetector) has a doubled quota (20,000) and the mobile apps have an [essentially unlimited quota](https://stackapps.com/q/8168/34061).

While cleaning up old comments might be a noble cause, simply deleting them programmatically is not the way to go. It even borders on 'self-destruction of useful content' (a.k.a. 'rage quitting') which is one of the stock reasons to suspend users temporarily. Comments fall under the [CC-BY-SA <s>2.5</s> <s>3.0</s> 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) license too, just like posts.

*If* you decide to delete old comments, please check whether the content is useful enough to be kept in the post instead. If it doesn't, have a look at other comments under the same post and consider flagging them as 'no longer needed' if they don't make sense anymore (because they were a reply to one of your comments). Flagging as 'no longer needed' doesn't impose any penalties on the user whose comment you're flagging.

Comment: Is there an mod flag raised if a user deletes 20 comments a day, over multiple days?

Comment: Thought comments were supposed to be temporary and eventually deleted.  How can comments be considered "self-destruction of helpful content"?

Comment: I'm under the impression - and this is *very* rare, there's an autoflag for mass comment deletions in some cases. I don't remember when I saw it though,

Comment: How cute that my comments were deleted by a mod. Well, now there is this question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339898/152799