# License violation

Tags: bug, comments, legal, licensing, creative-commons

The [CC BY-CA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode) states

> Section 3 – License Conditions.
>
> Your exercise of the Licensed Rights is expressly made subject to the following conditions.
>
> a. Attribution.
>
> 1. If You Share the Licensed Material (including in modified form), You must:
>
>    A. [...]
>
>    B.           indicate if You modified the Licensed Material and retain an indication of any previous modifications; and

However when moderators edit user's comments, there is no indication that a comment was modified by a non-Licensor.

Thus SO violates the Section  [3(a)(1)(B)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode#s3a1B) of the CC BY-CA 4.0.

Fix this ASAP.

Comment: @WeareMonica I don't see how you deleting a comment is at all relevant. You don't need law degrees (let alone international law) to be able to read a license and use some common sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is proper attribution given when a moderator edits someone's comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248537/is-proper-attribution-given-when-a-moderator-edits-someones-comment)

Comment: @CodyGray The linked question deals with version 3 of the license and this question here with version 4 of it, which has a difference in that regard. I could imagine that the answers are not identical.